# Is it possible to run object method using Object's ID?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Object with method created by Object Constructor:

```
 function objectexample(name) {
        this.name = name;

    this.create = function(){
    var obj = document.createElement('div');
    obj.id = this.name;
    parent = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    parent.appendChild(obj);
    }

     this.showalert = function(){
     alert("alert"); 
    }

    }
```

And now I create object:

```
var obj1 = new objectexample("new1");
```

How to run method .create for this object, but not using variable obj1, I want to get Object using ID, for example:

```
 document.getElementById("new1").showalert();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible getElementById("new1") will give u a different object which is dom object not the objectexample object

Comment: but you can do the contrary: create a JS object that saves inside a var a reference to the DOM object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is a variable name, not an object id.

`document.getElementById` has nothing to do with Javascript variable names, but rather is used for selecting elements from an HTML document by their id. However, it is possible to do this in several different ways depending on your use case.

One way could be to use a global/neatly scoped object in which you would modify every time the constructor is called.

```js
let objects = {}; // create your global object

function objectexample(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // append this to global object
    objects[name] = this;
    
    this.create = function(){
      var obj = document.createElement('div');
      obj.id = this.name;
      parent = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      parent.appendChild(obj);
    }

    this.showalert = function(){
      alert("alert"); 
    }

}

new objectexample("new1");

console.log(objects.new1)
console.log(objects["new1"]) // alternatively method
```

Answer (score 1):

## Basically, yes, it is possible

However, you'll need the element to contain a reference to the object that created it.

In the demo below:

- When constructing the `new` `obj1`, we define 3 properties:

  1. Its `name`.
  2. A `create()` method that when called creates an element.
  3. A `showAlert()` method that when called outputs some data.
- When calling `showAlert()` before calling `create()`, we get whatever data is available about the object, but nothing about the as yet uncreated element.
- When calling `create()` we create the element, and define `creation` as a property of the object, with the element as its value.
- We then define `creator` as a property of the element, with the value of `this` (the object that created the element).
- Now the object (`creator`) has a child element called `creation`, and the element has a `creator` and all the properties it has, including its methods.

In other words, if the `new` object gives birth to an element, the element adopts its creator's properties, and the creator keeps a tight hold of its child's hand.

```js
function ObjectExample( name ) {
  this.name = name;

  this.create = function() {
    this.creation = document.createElement( "div" );
    this.creation.id = name;
    this.creation.creator = this;
    document.body.appendChild( this.creation );
  }

  this.showAlert = function() {
    // alert( "Alert!" ); // simpler for demo to use console
    console.log( this.name );
    console.log( this.creation );
    return this.creation;
  }
}

let obj1 = new ObjectExample( "new1" );

if ( !obj1.showAlert() ) {
  obj1.create();
}

document.getElementById( "new1" ).creator.showAlert();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it haven't worked completely as I wanted. Yes, it runs the method, but inside method I can't get object properties, for example: **this.name** will return **null**.

Comment: @Tomson_PL - I didn't see the requirement before; I have included that functionality. I've opted to `console.log` in the demo for ease.